# List-initialization priority from object of same type

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer, overload-resolution, list-initialization

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
using namespace std;

struct CL
{
    CL(){}
    CL (std::initializer_list<CL>){cout<<1;}
    CL (const CL&){cout<<2;}
};

int main()
{
    CL cl1;
    CL cl2 {cl1}; //prints 21
}
```

Here is *CL* struct with copy constructor and initializer-list constructor. I think only copy constructor must be called here, because according to C++ 14 Standard, 8.5.4/3

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as
> follows:
> — If T is a class type and the initializer list has a
> single element of type cv U, where U is T or a class derived from T,
> the object is initialized from **that element** (by copy-initialization
> for copy-list-initialization, or by direct-initialization for
> direct-list-initialization).
> — Otherwise, ...

In other words, the initialization of *cl2* must be performed from *cl1* element, but not from the initializer-list *{cl1}*. Clang and gcc both print "21", only Visual Studio prints "2" and I think it's correct.
There are two candidate constructors for taking an argument *cl1* of type CL:

1. Constructor with `std::initializer_list<CL>` (passes because no such conversion from CL to `std::initializer_list<CL>`)
2. Copy constructor with const CL& (exact match with only qualification conversion non-const->const)

Who is right? Whose behavior is correct?

Comment: What compiler? I can't reproduce with clang. I get `2` as expected.

Comment: @juanchopanza which version of clang? ;)

Comment: using online compiler: clang 3.6 says `21` but clang 3.7 says `2` ; all vers of g++ up to 5.2 say `21`

Comment: @n.m. Whatever apple llvm 7.0.0 corresponds to.

Comment: C++11 had a lot of problems with braced-initialization and attempted copy-construction  in fact calling some other constructor... some of those cases were fixed for C++14

Comment: I used the compiler on http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_clang. There are clang 3.6 and gcc 4.9.2

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using the published C++14 standard?  (If not, and you're referring to a draft, please specify which draft)

Comment: To future readers: this question refers to an old version of the standard (draft). For a newer standard (draft), please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35273025/5376789).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr:** The published C++14 text specified output `21`. However, the behaviour of this code was changed by [CWG Issue 1467](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467), which gained the status of Defect in November 2014.

Defect Reports are considered to apply retroactively. clang 3.7 and VS2015 have applied the resolution suggested by this defect report, which appears in C++17 drafts as of N4296.

---

Prior to this defect report, the behaviour was covered by this text from N4140 [over.match.list]:

> When objects of **non-aggregate** class type `T` are list-initialized (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> - Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class T and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
> - If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.
>
> If the initializer list has no elements and T has a default constructor, the first phase is omitted. In copy-list-initialization, if an explicit constructor is chosen, the initialization is ill-formed. [Note: This differs from other situations (13.3.1.3, 13.3.1.4), where only converting constructors are considered for copy-initialization. This restriction only applies if this initialization is part of the final result of overload resolution.
>   —end note ]

Your class is not an aggregate because it has a user-provided constructor.

The above text is directed-to by the following bullet point in [dcl.init.list]/3:

> - Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7).

So, in the published C++14, the initializer-list constructor should actually be preferred to the copy-constructor, if it matches. C++11 had the same text.

---

In your question you say that C++14 contains:

> If `T` is a class type and the initializer list has a single element of type [...]

This text was not in C++14, but applied at a later date by a defect report. In the updated standard with the defect report applied (N4296), this appears as a bullet point higher up in the list of bullet points in [dcl.init.list]/3; so now the copy-constructor is selected ealier in the process and we do not get so far as the above [over.match.list] step.

Note that although the defect is titled *List-initialization of aggregate from same-type object*, the resolution actually affects initialization of both aggregates and non-aggregates.

Comment: Hopefully this defect resolution puts to bed all of the issues with copy-constructors not being selected when intended

Comment: Yes, I used N4296 Standard with that correction. Thanks