# C++ Copy constructor gets called instead of initializer_list<>

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, initializer-list, list-initialization

Based on this code

```
struct Foo 
{
   Foo() 
   {
       cout << "default ctor" << endl;
   }

   Foo(std::initializer_list<Foo> ilist) 
   {
       cout << "initializer list" << endl;
   }

   Foo(const Foo& copy)
   {
       cout << "copy ctor" << endl;
   }
};

int main()
{

   Foo a;
   Foo b(a); 

   // This calls the copy constructor again! 
   //Shouldn't this call the initializer_list constructor?
   Foo c{b}; 



   _getch();
   return 0;
}
```

The output is:

**default ctor**

**copy ctor**

**copy ctor**

In the third case, I'm putting b into the brace-initialization which should call the initializer_list<> constructor.

Instead, the copy constructor takes the lead.

Will someone of you tell me how this works and why?

Comment: Looks like something weird is going on g++ gives [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/434333cc75ac810d) while clang gives [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/501ecb5964d240c7)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*As pointed out by Nicol Bolas, the original version of this answer was incorrect: cppreference at the time of writing incorrectly documented the order in which constructors were considered in list-initialization. Below is an answer using the rules as they exist in the n4140 draft of the standard, which is very close to the official C++14 standard.*

*The text of the original answer is still included, for the record.*

---

#### Updated Answer

Per NathanOliver's comment, gcc and clang produce different outputs in this situation:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
default ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
initializer list


clang++ -std=c++14 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
default ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
```

gcc is correct.

n4140 [dcl.init.list]/1

> List-initialization is initialization of an object or reference from a braced-init-list.

You're using list-initialization there, and since `c` is an object, the rules for its list-initialization are defined in [dcl.init.list]/3:

[dcl.init.list]/3:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> 1. If `T` is an aggregate...
> 2. Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements...
> 3. Otherwise, if `T` is a specialization of `std::initializer_list<E>`...

going through the list so far:

1. `Foo` is not an aggregate.
2. It has one element.
3. `Foo` is not a specialization of `std::initializer_list<E>`.

Then we hit [dcl.init.list]/3.4:

> Otherwise, if `T` is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7). If a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed.

Now we're getting somewhere. 13.3.1.7 is also known as [over.match.list]:

> **Initialization by list-initialization**
>   When objects of non-aggregate class type `T` are list-initialized (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> 1. Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
> 2. If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.

So the copy constructor will only be considered *after* the initializer list constructors, in the second phase of overload resolution. The initializer list constructor should be used here.

It's worth noting that [over.match.list] then continues with:

> If the initializer list has no elements and `T` has a default constructor, the first phase is omitted. In copy-list initialization, if an explicit constructor is chosen, the initialization is ill-formed.

and that after [dcl.init.list]/3.**5** deals with single-element list initialization:

> Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element of type `E` and either `T` is not a reference type or its referenced type is reference-related to `E`, the object or reference is initialized from that element; if a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert the element to `T`, the program is ill-formed.

which explains where cppreference got their special case for single-element list initialization, though they placed it higher in the order than it should be.

---

#### Original Answer

You're encountering an interesting aspect of list initialization, where if the list fulfills certain requirements it may be treated like a copy-initialization rather than a list-initialization.

from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

> The effects of list initialization of an object of type `T` are:
>
> If `T` is a class type and the initializer list has a single element of
>   the same or derived type (possibly cv-qualified), the object is
>   initialized from that element (by copy-initialization for
>   copy-list-initialization, or by direct-initialization for
>   direct-list-initialization). (since c++14)

`Foo c{b}` fulfills all these requirements.

Comment: Why then if I write Foo c{a,b} the output is first "copy ctor" and then "initializer-list" ?

Comment: @Dunno `std::initializer_list` makes copies of its contents.

Comment: @Dunno technically, it doesn't write "copy ctor initializer list" but "copy ctor copy ctor initializer list" as it copies both elements in the initializer list to create the initializer list. With more than one element in the list, the requirement "has a single element" is no longer fulfilled, so it chooses the initializer list constructor.

Comment: So in short, the initializer-list method calls as much times the copy-ctor as the number of Foo elements I write in the braces. And, finally, if the number of Foo elements is greater than 1, then and only then calls **also** the initializer list? Correct?

Comment: @Dunno pretty much. Note that an *empty* initializer list will call the default copy constructor if it exists.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Don't you mean « default constructor » instead of « default copy constructor »?

Comment: @jaggedSpire I'm having troubles with your quotation in the answer. Look at this screenshot http://i.imgur.com/0grAUqq.jpg. I'm passing one parameter in the initializer-list and still I see `copy ctor` together with `initializer list`. So, the initializer list is always called when using **{ }**, and the copy ctors I see are just those who are needed by the initializer-list constructor. Correct?

Comment: @gedamial if you're using gcc, [it's a bug and is noted on the gcc bug tracker](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71205).

Comment: @gedamial incorrect. The rules for actually *calling* the initializer-list constructor are actually fairly complicated, though they do make a nice [list](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3). At any rate, [clang displays the expected behavior of calling the copy constructor in this instance](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e49f2275a8ef061). To figure out what should happen here, go down the list: the first statement fits the situation: a single element of type `Foo` inside the brackets, using [direct-list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)...

Comment: then the initialization effectively used is direct-initialization, which selects the most fitting of all constructors with the set of supplied arguments, which here is a single value of type `Foo`. Since you have defined a copy constructor taking a single argument of type `Foo`, that is the constructor it selects. *Again, this is the standard-specified behavior, which gcc apparently doesn't quite follow.*

Comment: @jaggedSpire: cpprefence is incorrect. See my answer for details, but suffice it to say that GCC is right here.

Comment: @NicolBolas it looks like the single element case cppreference mentions is simply lower priority than they have it listed as, placed as it is in [dcl.init.list]3.5. Still, this answer is wrong. May I correct it to use language from the standard, though this will make it quite similar to yours?

Comment: I'd offer to delete, but apparently you can't do that on an accepted answer (TIL)

Comment: @jaggedSpire: "*May I correct it to use language from the standard, though this will make it quite similar to yours?*" That's fine; I just want the information out there.

Comment: @NicolBolas edited. Does it meet with your approval?

Comment: @NicolBolas I believe back when this question was posted (february), cppreference was reflecting the state of the language after http://wg21.link/cwg1467 but before http://wg21.link/cwg2137 . It changed since then.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. I notice that MSVC++ and Clang are printing the same thing, whereas GCC prints it's own version.

It's a 2 versus 1. So in this case GCC is the winner?

I'm a clang user, very sad about this...

@Cubbi

Answer (score 6):

Let us examine what the C++14 specification says about list initialization here. [dcl.init.list]3 has a sequence of rules which are to be applied in order:

3.1 does not apply, since `Foo` is not an aggregate.

3.2 does not apply, since the list is not empty.

3.3 does not apply, since `Foo` is not a specialization of `initializer_list`.

3.4 does apply, since `Foo` is a class type. It says to consider constructors with overload resolution, in accord with [over.match.list]. And that rule says to check `initializer_list` constructors *first*. Since your type has an `initilaizer_list` constructor, the compiler *must* check to see if an `initializer_list` matching one of those constructors can be manufactured from the given values. It can, so ***that is what must be called***.

In short, GCC is right and Clang *is wrong*.

It should be noted that the C++17 working draft changes *nothing* about this. It has a new section 3.1 that has special wording for single-value lists, but that *only applies to aggregates*. `Foo` is not an aggregate, so it does not apply.

Comment: Looks like this question mentions gcc and clang only in the comment section.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan: True, but I found *this* question thanks to another question that was marked as a duplicate of this one. That question (which was needlessly deleted by its owner) had examples from Clang and GCC showing the differences between them.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I am the owner :) I deleted it supposing that it was too similar to this one.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan: Yes, being too similar is why it was closed as a duplicate. But deleting it means that I can't *reference it*. I can't point to similar code and show how GCC gets it right and Clang gets it wrong.

Comment: Why is the copy costructor called before the initializer_list costructor? @NicolBolas

Comment: @gedamial: Because Clang has a bug in it. The standard makes it clear that the `initializer_list` constructor should be called. If your compiler does not do that, then it is buggy.

Comment: @NicolBolas no, I was talking about GCC. Foo c{b} produces a call to the copy constructor **and then** to the initializer_list constructor

Comment: @gedamial: Yes. It has to create an `initializer_list`, which is a reference to a temporary array containing a copy of `b`. Then, `c` can be initialized with that `initializer_list`.

Comment: @NicolBolas so, in short, the initializer_list **needs** a copy constructor for constructing itself, right? Had I written Foo c{b,d,e,f,g} there would've been a copy of all of those objects, right?

Comment: @gedamial: `initializer_list` references an array, so it doesn't copy anything. When the compiler sees a braced-init-list and uses it to create an `initializer_list`, it *also* creates a temporary array that actually holds copies of the elements from the braced-init-lists. That is when the copy constructor is being invoked. It would be no different from doing `auto c = {b, d, e, f, g};`