# Issue with std::initializer_list constructor and "braced initialization"

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, initializer-list, list-initialization

Consider the following code:

```
#include <initializer_list>

class C {
public:
    C() = delete;
    C(int) {}
};

class D {
public:
    D(std::initializer_list<C> il) {} 
};

int main()
{
    std::initializer_list<C> il{};  // fine: empty list, no need to construct C
    D d2(il);                       // fine: calls initializer_list ctor with empty list
    D d3{il};                       // ditto
    D d4({});                       // still fine
    D d5{{}};                       // error: use of deleted function 'C::C()' 
                                    // WHY is the constructor of 'C' required here?
}
```

I thought `D d5{{}};` would call the `initializer_list` constructor of `D` with an empty list. And, as the list is empty, the constructor of `C` would not be called. However, it does not compile:

> error: use of deleted function `'C::C()'` -- `D d5{{}};`

What is the rationale behind this error?

#### Update

An issue on page 55 in Scott Meyer's "Effective Modern C++" made me think that having empty braces in a braced initialization would call the `initializer_list` constructor with an empty list. That is wrong. For details, see [this blog post](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2016/11/help-me-sort-out-meaning-of-as.html) from the author.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273025/c-copy-constructor-gets-called-instead-of-initializer-list ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`D d5{{}};` attempts to initialize `d5` with a one-element initializer list. That one element is `{}` which is a shorthand for `C{}` - a default-constructed instance of `C`. But `C` doesn't have a default constructor - hence the error.

Comment: Ahh, you mean `D d5{{}}` is the same as `D d5{C{}}`?

Comment: @sergej Yes. It's easy to demonstrate experimentally - just modify the program to have `C()` constructor print something, and/or have `D`'s list constructor print the size of the list.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik how were you able to diagnose this issue? did you add `couts` to the `ctors`as mentioned in your comments?

Comment: @PYA No, just from the error message and first principles. I haven't compiled the code.