# C++ std::vector initializer_list overload ambiguity (g++/clang++)

Tags: c++, stdvector, initializer-list, uniform-initialization

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <vector>

#define BROKEN

class Var {
public:
#ifdef BROKEN
    template <typename T>
    Var(T x) : value(x) {}
#else
    Var(int x) : value(x) {}
#endif

    int value;
};

class Class {
public:
    Class(std::vector<Var> arg) : v{arg} {}

    std::vector<Var> v;
};
```

Clang++ (7.0.1) compiles this without errors whether or not `BROKEN` is defined, but g++ (8.2.1) raises an error if `BROKEN` is defined:

```
main.cpp:9:20: error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<Var>’ to ‘int’ in initialization
  Var(T x) : value(x) {}
                    ^
```

As far as I know, the uniform intialization used here should select the `std::vector(std::vector&&)` constructor in both cases; apparently, however, `g++` instead sees the `{arg}` as an initializer list and tries to initialize the first element of `v` with `Var` applied to a vector, which won't work.

If `BROKEN` is not defined, g++ is apparently smart enough to realize that the initializer_list overload isn't going to work.

Which is the correct behavior, or are both allowed by the standard?

[BROKEN defined gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LBw3Pu2f07hMy13R)
[BROKEN not defined gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/j6ZAJpr4oeqnLpbP)
[BROKEN defined clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nJAZMZpfz69bQ5Nm)

Comment: I'm no expert, but an interesting data point here: if you mark the ctor `explicit` then g++ likes it better.

Comment: Another data point: https://godbolt.org/z/gsc48J (you can play around with different optimization levels). Apparently, gcc calls `Var::Var<std::vector<Var> >(std::vector<Var>)` after the copy constructor of `std::vector` is called.

Comment: The same reason as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35273025/5376789).

Comment: @xskxzr If I understand that correctly, this means that clang considers the type error in the initialization list (`: value(x)`) to mean that the constructor is not viable, while gcc already decided that a constructor is viable before looking at the initialization list. Given that the initialization list may, in general, be in a different compilation unit, gcc's behaviour seems appropriate, making clang's incorrect. Is that true?

Comment: @tomsmeding: Clang does not consider `template <typename T> Var(T x)`, even if you remove the function body. The post linked by @xskxzr does not involve any possible type errors inside the constructor or initializer-list.

Answer (score 2):

Here is are two ways to fix that issue:

```
class Var {
public:
#ifdef BROKEN
    template <typename T>
    Var(T x, typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, int>::value>::type* = nullptr) : value(x) {}
#else
    Var(int x) : value(x) {}
#endif

    int value;
};
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ECbXGyXU0atzjNuq).

Or:

```
class Class {
public:
    Class(std::vector<Var> arg) : v(arg) {}

    std::vector<Var> v;
};
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tkZvfMxmdf3wAhSY).

Now apparently in case of gcc tries use template parameter as initialization list. When braces are used and initialization list is defined, initialization list has higher priority then copy constructor.

So adding proper `enable_if` solves the problem since it protects from creating initialization list version of constructor. In C++20 concepts will solve this in better way.

And when parenthesis instead braces are used to initialize `v` initialization list is not preferable.

I'm not sure who is right (IMO clang, but this is just a gut feeling). Maybe someone who knows standard better can tell.

Comment: How would `template <typename T> Var(T x);` be a case for SFINAE? 
I don't think the function body (or initializer-list) is relevant, especially since it could be in a different compilation unit.