# c++11 invoke a type conversion while moving an object

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a simple code, I compiled the code on GCC 5, 6, and 8 and deployed it to a physical testbed that uses gcc 4.8.3 for some reason, the code fails to compile on the testbed (ubuntu 14.04), I have been scratching my head to figure out what the problem is, but so far nothing. I copied the code below,

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

struct probe_payload
{
    int id{0};
    int sub_id{0};
    int snd_ts{0};
    int rcv_ts{0};
    int rtt_ms{1000};
    double snd_bw_bps{0};
    bool end_flag{false};
};

struct probe_message
{
  public:
    using buffer_t = void const *;

    probe_payload info;
    char shim[1280];

};

template<typename Packet>
struct parcel
{
    explicit parcel(Packet&& object, int ts) : item{std::move(object)}
    {
        arrival_time = std::move(ts);
    }

    parcel() = delete;
    parcel(const parcel<Packet>& /* other */) = default;
    parcel<Packet>& operator=(const parcel<Packet>& /* other */) = default;
    parcel(parcel<Packet>&& /* other */) = default;
    parcel<Packet>& operator=(parcel<Packet>&& /* other */) = default;

    Packet item;
    int arrival_time{0};
};


template <typename T>
parcel<T> get_parcel()
{
    T a;
    return parcel<T>{std::move(a), 10};
}


int main()
{
    auto p = get_parcel<probe_message>();
    return p.arrival_time;
}
```

> : In instantiation of 'parcel::parcel(Packet&&, int)
>   [with Packet = probe_message]':
>
> :48:38:   required from 'parcel get_parcel() [with T =
>   probe_message]'
>
> :54:40:   required from here
>
> :28:67: error: could not convert 'std::move((*
>   & object))' from 'std::remove_reference::type {aka
>   probe_message}' to 'probe_payload'
>
> explicit parcel(Packet&& object, int ts) : item{std::move(object)}

I've attached the link from [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/52jeuf).

Comment: why didn't you just write `using buffer_t = void const *;` ?

Comment: Maybe it is just a bug in gcc 4

Comment: I actually copied it from another file, void const * makes more sense, u r right

Comment: @M.M: I think it is a compiler bug as well, can u think of a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this GCC version does not like the brace-initialization `item{std::move(object)}`. It compiles with `item(std::move(object))` though.

[live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5VK2h5eRSWGyqJsv)

Answer (score 2):

The essence of the problem can be reduced to:

```
#include <utility>

struct probe_message
{
    int id;
};

int main()
{
    probe_message a;
    probe_message b{std::move(a)};
}
```

which is rejected by gcc 4.9.4, accepted by gcc 5+ and fixed by replacing `{ }` with `( )`.

I believe this is the same problem as in [List-initialization priority from object of same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33970892/), addressed by DR 1467.

gcc 4 does aggregate initialization with the list, and fails to convert `std::move(a)` to `int`.  Later versions do copy-construction or move-construction from a list of 1 element of the same type.

The Defect Report was not resolved until after C++14 publication, too late for gcc 4 it seems.